# Chaining Subjects - RxJS / Angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am *very* new to observables and I'm trying to get my mind around a good way to chain subjects. Essentially, I'm trying to take an array of observables that will all emit the same type and chain them together so that, when I call `next` on the first subject, every subsequent subject (assuming no `error` happens in between) gets a chance to take the value, manipulate it, and pass it on to the following subject until it reaches the last subject, which will emit the final result.

I've rolled my own class for dealing with this but it seems like this particular case would come up *all the time* with observables so I was wondering if anyone knows of anything that's already built into RxJS or Angular2 that does this.

Also, am I trying to force Subjects to do something they aren't meant to do? Is there a better way to go about chaining algorithms together in such a way each function has an opportunity to manipulate the input in turn before it's finally returned, with potential to error out if I need to? What's considered "best practice" in this circumstance?

**EDIT**

To be a little more clear what I'm talking about, this is something like what I'm looking for:

```
var wrapper = Subject.chain(subject1, subject2, subject3)

// Subscriptions happen here

/** 
 * This calls subject1.next("HI"), 
 * which then calls subject2.next() with the result of subject1's manipulation of "HI",
 * which then calls subject3.next() with the result of subject2's manipulation of the subject1's manipulation of "HI",
 * which then emits the result of subject3's manipulation of subject2's manipulation of subject1's manipulation of "HI"
 */
wrapper.next("HI");
```

**WORKAROUND**

In case someone finds this in the future, this is the workaround I used with the help of the `Array.reduce` function. It's not perfect but it'll do for me:

```
chain<T>(source: Observable<T>, destination: Subject<T>): Observable<T>
{
    let processed = false;
    return source.catch(
        err => {
            let ret = new ReplaySubject<T>(1);
            destination.first().subscribe(ret);
            processed = true;
            destination.error(err);
            return ret;
        }
    ).finally(
        () => {
            // TODO: Allow sources to not propagate complete status
            !processed && destination.complete();
            processed = true;
        }
    ).flatMap(
        (next: T) => {
            let ret = destination;
            if(!processed)
            {
                ret = new ReplaySubject<T>(1);
                destination.first().subscribe(ret);
                destination.next(next);
            }
            processed = false;
            return ret;
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To chain observables, you should consider using operators like `flatMap` or `switchMap`.

Here is a sample with HTTP:

```
this.http.get('...')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .flatMap(data => {
      // receive the result of the first request
      // use this result to execute another one
      return this.http.get('...')
              .map(res => res.json());
    }).subscribe(data => {
      // receive the result of the second request
    });
```

If you're interested in a good tutorial on this, you could have a look at this one:

- https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754

Comment: Is there a way to do this when you have an arbitrary-length list? Should I create a recursive function to handle that?

Comment: How will you create your list? Do you want to execute things in series or parallel? Do you want to aggregate results or only the one at the end?

Comment: I would like to execute things in series. Once an observable has a result, it passes it to the next observable to manipulate as it will and so on. There should be one value at the end. In my particular case, the result type is consistent throughout but I don't think it necessarily needs to be that way. I would like it to be a structure that I can pass from place to place that behaves like a subject so that, when you emit something, the wrapping structure calls the underlying subjects and emits the result of the chain. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it use subscribe to chain the subjects.

```
subject1
    .subscribe( subject2 );

subject2
    .subscribe( subject3 );

subject3
    .subscribe( x=> {
        // do you want to do
    });
```